What is the maximum no of incoming api calls per second?
I am trying to understand if there is any limit around maximum no of incoming api calls per second in Salesforce.
Generally for non salesforce systems, load server/system can handle is measured in QPS (Queries per second) or TPS (Transactions per second). However, nothing is called out like this in documentation for salesforce.
In Salesforce there are multiple limits like:

Maximum number of parallel transactions taking more than 5 seconds.
Maximum incoming api call limits per day (based on licenses)

Assuming the api calls are taking less than 5 seconds and api limit is quite high.
Based on this below are my questions:

What is the maximum no of incoming api calls per second ?
Has anyone observed degradation of system after particular no of parallel api calls ?


There is no such limit. You can see this in the docs

There isn’t a limit on the number of concurrent requests shorter than 20 seconds.

The above is from the docs link below
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm
